# After upgrading TortoiseSVN, all my icon overlays have disappeared

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have read FAQ in [this link](http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#ovlnotshowing).

Then I changed tortoisesvn setting as the below, but the problem still exist, what should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
right click anywhere in that folder -> TortoiseSVN -> Clean up...
in that dialog box check Refresh Shell Overlays and click on OK
```

this will work if it's an issue with only refreshing. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @DiariB Well this happened only once when i changed the version. The files got corrupted and i had to manually add them again. Sorry i couldn't be of help.

Answer (score 0):

This what worked for me:

http://www.sitepoint.com/missing-tortoisesvn-file-status-overlay-icons/

From the above link:

> The problem is caused by the number of overlays permitted in different
>   versions of Windows. Vista 32-bit appears to support 15 overlay types,
>   whereas Windows 7 64-bit supports 11. Installing a program which adds
>   its own icon overlays can therefore disable them in another
>   application.

After I removed a few unnecessary ones (you have to determine what is *unnecessary*), I got my icons back.